# F# class constructor with no args --- error using filehelpers wtih f#

Tags: c#, csv, constructor, f#, filehelpers

I followed the link of [parse CSV using F# and filehelpers](http://www.markstaples.com/2009/01/08/parsing-csv-files-in-f/). got compiler error for the following code `"The record class oneRow need a constructor with no args (public or private)"`

```
[<DelimitedRecord(",")>]
type oneRow=
  class
    [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/d/yyyy")>]
    val date: DateTime
    val value: bool
  end
let engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof<oneRow>)
let tmp = engine.ReadFile("test.csv")
```

**EDIT**
The solution looks quite verbose than c# version. I need add `()`, `mutable` and `[<DefaultValue>]`

```
  type oneRow() =
      class
        [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/d/yyyy")>]
        [<DefaultValue>]
        val mutable date: DateTime
        [<DefaultValue>]
        val mutable value: bool
      end
```

But similar code works in C# without specify a constructor. Could anyone help me fix the F# code? thanks.

Comment: To make it a little less verbose, you can omit `class` and `end` using F# light syntax (which is the default these days). Also note that in F#, immutability is the default, so you do have to go out of your way to make mutable types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# will create you a constructor. F# doesn't (presumably because parameterless constructors imply mutability, and so are not exactly encouraged.)

For example, in your code - how are you going to set those properties, they're still immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the verbose syntax - It can be made nicer. The sample was written some time ago (2 years), so it is still using a little old syntax. It could be updated to allow writing something like this:

```
[<DelimitedRecord(",")>]
type OneRow
   ( [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/d/yyyy")>] 
     date:DateTime,
     value:bool ) =
   member x.Date = date
   member x.Value = value
```

I believe this is a lot nicer (and by moving annotations to the constructor, you can also implement your own functionality in the type and e.g. hide some fields). The only change that needs to be done is to modify the parser to find attributes on constructor parameters (and not fields).

Comment: This does not compile for the date convert line, but the old format above compiles on vs2010.

Comment: More info on why this example does not work.  The FieldConvertor attribute causes the error "The attribute is not valid for this element".  Is there anyway to resolve this?  (my guess is no, but still too new to F# to know).

Answer (score 0):

yes, it should be `type oneRow () =` with parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, i think it would work if a ctor is added into oneRow.

```
new () = { date = new DateTime() ; value = false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the posts concerning FileHelpers are rather dated. In some cases though it's nice to use instead of the csv type provider. One can use the `CLIMutable` attribute on an F# record to have a default constructor and in this case FileHelpers will happily write and read the csv file:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#I @"..\packages\FileHelpers\lib\net45"
#r "FileHelpers.dll"
#endif

open FileHelpers
open System

[<DelimitedRecord(",");CLIMutable>]
type TestFileHelp =
    {test1:string
     test2:string
     [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd")>]
     date:DateTime
    }

let f1 = [|{test1="a";test2="b";date=DateTime.Now};{test1="c";test2="d";date=DateTime.Now}|]
let fengine = new FileHelperEngine<TestFileHelp>()
fengine.WriteFile(@"c:\tmp\testrec.csv",f1)
```